# OAuth 2 Google - Access Control

Tags: postgresql, vuejs2, oauth-2.0, java-8, google-oauth

I'm working with Vue.js 2, Java on the backend and PostgreSQL database. It's my first time working with OAuth 2 authentications and with Google.

I still have some doubts about the process, I haven't found any information easier to understand.

I've already managed to use Google's button render and the user is now able to log in to his Google account.

What I wanted to know is:

If my user has already logged in to his email and I get the id token, which is the "credential" attribute that Google responds to, would I no longer be able to log that user into my system or is it still not secure?

I've read that it has a long process beyond that, like getting the authorization token and then exchanging that token for the access token. Do I really have to follow this entire process? Is safer? It's very likely that I don't need to use the Google APIs right now, I just want to login, but maybe in the future it will be interesting.

Also, what am I supposed to save in my users table? Any of these tokens?

What should my '/login' endpoint receive from a user using Google authentication for me to verify and login to my application? How would I control to keep him logged in and log out?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to a sibgle, focused question.